# Selecting proper div class with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have a html with 3 types of `div` classes:

```
<div class="message">
<div class="message message__current">
<div class="message message__current message--grouped">
```

When I do

```
all_messages_2 = soup.find_all("div", class_="message message__current")
```

it selects only type 2 of `div`.

But then when I want to select only type 1 and I do

```
all_messages_1 = soup.find_all("div", class_="message")
```

it selects all 3 types of `div`.

Could you help, please?

Comment: You forgot to tell us what you would like to achieve? select the third div or the second?

Comment: First I want to select only `<div class="message message__current">` and do some operations on the content. Then I want to select only `<div class="message">` and do similar operations. So I have the problem with second selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a lambda to select each div tag with the class attribute matches what you want exactly.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="message">
<div class="message message__current">
<div class="message message__current message--grouped">
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


tags = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'div' and tag.get('class') == ['message'])
print (len(tags))

tags = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'div' and tag.get('class') == ['message', 'message__current'])
print (len(tags))

tags = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'div' and tag.get('class') == ['message', 'message__current', 'message--grouped'])
print (len(tags))
```

Outputs:

```
1
1
1
```

Note the way it is without closing tags will get interpreted as all the tags close at the end of your HTML. So selecting text from the first will have all the text from the other two as well. Likewise selecting text from the second will have text from the third.

Comment: @ Dan-Dev, thanks for the demo. Plus one for this. For the last few days I've been trying to understand `lambda` function and seeing your demo it seems I'm beginning to understand it. However, could you provide any link where I can learn more of it. Thanks again.

Comment: @novice-coder a quick google search shows many results. At a quick glance https://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php seems to cover most of what you want to know.

Comment: Thank you @Dan-Dev